# Why I'm I getting a 405 Method Not Allowed when submitting forms - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm working on a countdown website where I have 2 forms in the same view, every time I submit 1 of those forms I'm getting a error that says:

```
"message": "The POST method is not supported for route /. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."
```

The method that I'm using in the view is a GET method and the method that I'm using in the action route of the forms are POST method.

Now, I'll show you the routes and the HTML:

My routes:

[image: routes]

HTML Form 1:

[image: html form 1]

HTML Form 2:

[image: html form 2]

I've tried by setting the hidden method with Laravel using `@method('POST')` in the form, but it doesn't even works, I've also tried setting the same route to the routes on the web.php file like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\EmailController::class, 'sendEmail'])->name('send.email');
Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\EmailController::class, 'saveEmail'])->name('save.email');
```

, but doesn't works too, every time I tried it, I was getting this error:

[image: error]

and other things that I have tried by watching YouTube tutorials and StackOverflow posts, but how I said before nothing works

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Please, do not post images, as the images go down so the questions is unusable in the future. Also, you did add tags laravel 5 and 8, which one are you using?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you for recommendation about the images, the laravel version im using is 'Laravel Framework 10.2.0'

Comment: You don't have a route for post to /

Comment: Your `form`s have no `method`, which means they default to `GET`.  But you only have (had?) `POST` methods set up for those named routes (confirmed in your routes screenshot).  I would not have thought using `@mehod('POST')` would work (it is a modifier to spoof the method when the method is a POST already), but maybe it does ... keep it simple, add a `method`, no need for `@method()`. Don't cache routes in development, if you have been, clear the cache.  Check browser devtools, look at the network tab when you submit - is the method correct?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic when i set the simple way of the method on the form, it doesnt works, and when i check the network there isnt a method parameter either.

Comment: To be clear, what does "*set the simple way of the method on the form*" mean?  The network tab will always show the method, every network request has a method.  It is not a parameter. If it is not displayed, click the request and choose the "Headers" tab, or right click the column headers and tick "method": https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `method="post"` to your `form` tag.

```html
<form action="{{ route("...") }}" method="post">
```

And check if Laravel cached your view or route, run `php artisan about` and see if it is cached.

It will show like this:

```bash
Cache ...............................................................................  
  Config ................................................................... NOT CACHED  
  Events ................................................................... NOT CACHED  
  Routes ................................................................... NOT CACHED  
  Views .................................................................... NOT CACHED
```

If it's cached, run `php artisan view:clear` to clear view cache, `php artisan route:clear` to clear routes cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your expected route is listed when you call
`php artisan route:list`

if your route is present in the list use the below in your view form action:
`action={{url(contact-form)}}`

Otherwise, use `php artisan optimize` in your terminal to reset your config and your routes.

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't works :c, cuz I'm still getting the 405 error method not allowed

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is with your route, try to make use of `resource()` in your route instead : ` Route::resource(EmailController::class, sendEmail)